# Prevent user to access if has not logged in

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on developing a simple web system, so an user first will be directed to a login page, then a processing page. If its account data provided is correct, it will be directed to the main page, so it can carry out some actions, at last it can logout.

So what I want to ask is: how can I prevent user to access the processing, main or logout page before they login, I mean, if I do not limit it, the login action is by some means useless. I am using wamp to develop the web system.

I have considered making use of the session variable, however, I have no idea how to check the value of the variable. If I start a session at the login page, so if I skip the login page but directed go to the main page, do I have those session variable present in the main page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Add `session_start();` at the top of the php page to initialize sessions.

2) Add if statement

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1) { ..show page.. } else { show login page }
```

3) Create a login form which validates data, if data is correct then it adds `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;` and redirects to profile page with logout button.

That's all :)!

I suggest that you check some tutorials, since it will give you some more information how to do that - http://www.intechgrity.com/create-login-admin-logout-page-in-php-w/ or any other link via google - "How to create login/logout functions with SESSIONS".

About your question, in each page you will put `session_start();` at the start of the file, they will have all sessions you have specified for user.

**EDIT:**

Added few useful links -

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: why not only add ``if(!$_SESSION['logged_in'])) { //redirect }`` to each non-login page?

Comment: Yes, it should work also ;)! Just showed him example. Thank you for editing :)

Comment: @Luceos, one could disable the redirects in the browser and therefore see the page anyway

Comment: I have some basic knowledge about using the session, but my concept is not quite clear, therefore I open the question to clearify it. So I should have the session_start() in every files? Then if I have it in every files, so when I go to the processing page from the login page, will the session being restarted?

Comment: If you will have session_start(); in each file, then all sessions will be same in each file, so basically if you specify the $_SESSION['logged_in'] in index.php file then it will be the same in admin.php file, if you will have session_start(); at top of the page. At logout you can just use $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 0; or session_unset (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php).  Please check also this link for more info http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @Roman, may I ask if someone diable the redirects in the browser, then how can I prevent them to see the things inside? If I change all the things in the main.php into echo one, so only if the condition being fulfilled, if not, nothing will be printed, is it a good method?

Comment: @user1502740 if my answer was helpful and it helped to resolve your problem, would you be so kind and accept it?

Comment: @Luceos, ok. that's essentially what the answer said ;)

Answer (score 0):

well,this is what i will do. Check with an if statement if a session variable that holds, for example, the username from the login page exists, then if it doesn't show an error 404 page, or redirect the user to any error page...you might want to create that yourself anyway (so that it redirects them back to the login page).

```
<?
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username']){
 header("Location: HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found", 404);
          exit;}
?>
```

You could also create a new file and place this code there so that you call it on everypage that will require a user to login before accessing it....

Answer (score 0):

but try to access non login page for the first time then you will be redirected to login page then try to access the same non login page for the second time you'll have the access already even you didn't log-in.